# Anyone find RDP Plug-in for MMC for Windows 7?

Tags: windows, windows-7, rdp

It used to let me open any of my RDP targets and switch between them.  Now, with the Win 7 RTM, it doesn't work anymore.  I'm accessing Server 2003 machines, so no Server 2008 suggestions, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like the one that comes with the Windows 7 [Remote Admin Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=7d2f6ad7-656b-4313-a005-4e344e43997d&displaylang=en)? Is that what you're after?

I like [mRemote](http://www.mremote.org/wiki/) for such things, for what that's worth.

Answer (score 0):

I've grown particularly fond of [RDTabs](http://www.avianwaves.com/Tech/Tools/RDTabs/) (freeware) for managing numerous Remote Desktop connections.  The nicest thing about it is its flexibility, allowing you to arrange things in a way that best suits your own working style.

From the software vendor:

> *Windows Remote Desktop is great, except when you have to connect to dozens of them and it fills up your taskbar! Enter RD Tabs: the ultimate tabbed Remote Desktop Client. Not only does it provide all the expected features of "tabbed" applications like FireFox, Opera, and IE7, but it takes Remote Desktop to the next level with features such as favorites with advanced editing, command line scripting, connection thumbnails, encrypted passwords, detached connection windows, remote desktop screen capture, remote terminal server information/management, RDP 6.0 support, and much more!*
>
> *In addition, RD Tabs is 100% Vista compatible and works perfectly as a standard (non-admin) user on all versions of Windows. Also, RD Tabs respects Windows' Remote Desktop Client group policy, for enterprise environments. To top it all off, automatic software updates keep you informed of all the latest versions, fixes, and enhancements.*

Comment: Just tried this one, too.  Had numerous navigation problems with 64 bit version.  I'll stick with mRemote.